# Debug QGIS python plugins

Tags: qgis, pydev

I'm writing a plugin for QGIS (3.10) in Python. I would like to follow the execution of the script line by line to understand some bugs. I installed **Remote Debug** plugin and tried to connect it with :

- *PyDev (Eclipse)*. I configured all as explained here: [How to set up Eclipse to develop QGIS scripts or plugins](https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/en/how-to-set-up-eclipse-to-develop-qgis-scripts-or-plugins/). But executing the plugin in QGIS still has no effect in Eclipse.
- *Winpdb-reborn*, but a window is opening in winpdpb showing the code of *Remote Debug* plugin and highlighting this line:

  ```py
  def statusBar(self): 
      return self.iface.mainWindow().statusBar()
  ```
- *Eric6*, and the connection seems to be OK in Eric6, but QGIS freezes as I click on "Connect" in *Remote Debug*.
- *First Aid* plugin seems not to be compatible with QGIS 3.

I don't know in what direction to go now. Does someone have a working solution to debug plugin in QGIS 3?

Comment: I would love to be able to run a proper debugger on a python script in qgis, but what I have ended up doing is using print() statements that will end up in the python console. Crude, but it has helped me a lot of times.

Comment: That's an option, but in my case, my script creates some empty layers, and i would like to understand when. I'm not sure a print() can help. I think i really need to control the execution line by line

Comment: Some years ago using pyCharm I got remote debugging working using this description: https://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/pycharm/. Don't know if it will work today.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [First Aid Plugin for QGIS](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/firstaid/) ([github page](https://github.com/wonder-sk/qgis-first-aid-plugin)).
This plugin really helps with plugin testing in QGIS 3+.

Comment: I have a "Module not found error" when i try to run my script in First Aid. "No module named '__main__.imported_classes'; '__main__' is not a package"